# Printing outout of a view in to a field in user profiles

Tags: views, users

I have created a view which prints only usernames of registered users .

In user registration there is field named "father username" .  i want that field to be populated as a list from the above view .

i used view reference , but it just shows all the views in the site .

any clue ?
thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by `In user registration there is field named "father username"` ? There is a field you added called `father username` on the signup form?

Comment: Yes there is a dropdown , to select father "Full Name" from already existing users .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an assumption, and answer based on the assumption. The assumption is that the field "Father username" is an entity reference field, and you want to use the view of registered users to populate the options for that field.

If that is so, you need to create an "entity reference" view display, then refer to that view display in the field settings of the "father username" field.

Comment: thanks worked perfectly , this is what i was looking for :)